# Fisher-Yates (java) vs. Collections.shuffle

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, shuffle

I'm still a beginner so please be kind. I have trouble understanding why the Fisher-Yates algorithm modifies the array elements permanently and the Collections' shuffle method doesn't. I suspect one reason is that I may not actually understand properly how the Fisher-Yates algorithm works, but I would appreciate any help. Code below:

import java.util.*;

public class ArrayShuffle {

```
private static char[] letters = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Collections' shuffle method:");
    shuffleCollections(letters);
    System.out.print(letters);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Fisher-Yates method:");
    shuffleFisherYates(letters);
    System.out.print(letters);

}

public static void shuffleCollections(char[] abc) {
    List letterList = new ArrayList();
    for(int alph=0; alph<abc.length; alph++)
        //convert char to ArrayList object
        letterList.add(abc[alph]);
    //shuffle
    Collections.shuffle(letterList);
    System.out.println(letterList);


}

public static void shuffleFisherYates(char[] abc) {
    int size = abc.length;
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int alph=0; alph<abc.length; alph++) {
        int randomIndex = alph + random.nextInt(size - alph);
        char randomLetter = abc[randomIndex];
        abc[randomIndex] = abc[alph];
        abc[alph] = randomLetter;
    }
    for(int shuffled = 0; shuffled<abc.length; shuffled++)
        System.out.print(abc[shuffled]+" ");
    System.out.println();

}
```

}

Comment: what's the input and output when you tried?

Comment: Well, you're simply copying the elements of your array to a list, and shuffling that list. Why would the array be modified? If the array was an array of objects, and you used Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array)), then the array would be shuffled (because Arrays.asList is a list view over the original array, not a copy).

Answer (score 1):

Your `shuffleFisherYates` modifies the input array directly (that's what `abc[someIndex] = ...;` does).

Your `shuffleCollections` builds an `ArrayList` based on the input array and then modifies that `ArrayList` (via the call to `Collections.shuffle(letterList)`). It doesn't modify the input array.

Comment: Thanks Eran. But is there any way to reverse the output back to the original using the Fisher-Yates method?

Comment: @Busybitsnbytes not unless you keep a copy of the original array as a backup.

Comment: I thought so too. Thanks very much!